# Vim multiple filtering of a file, with 2 filters based upon number values

Tags: vim

I do not know if that title will sound adequate …

Let us say I have a file (> 1000 lines) with a homogeneous structure throughout consisting of three "fields" separated by a space :

```
1. an integer (negative or positive)
   <space>
2. another integer (negative or positive)
   <space>
3. some text (description)
```

The integers are >-10000 and < 10000

My problem is : how can I

a) filter this file with criteria such as "1st integer <= 1000" AND "2nd integer >=250" AND "text contains : Boston OR New-York"

b) and put the subset in a new buffer, allowing me to read the results and only the results of the filter(s) ?

I wish to do that with Vim only, not knowing if it is feasible or reasonable (anyway it is above my skills)

Thanks

---

@FDinoff : sorry, I should have done what you suggest, of course :

It could be a chronology with a StartDate, an EndDate, and a Description :

```
1 -200 -50 Period one in Italy
2 -150 250 Period one in Greece
3  -50  40 Period two in Italy 
4   10  10 Some event in Italy
5   20  20 Event two in Greece
```

The filter could be : Filter the items where (to mimic SQL) StartDate <=-50 AND EndDate >=0 AND Description contains Greece, with a resulting filter => line 2

Comment: Example input and output please?

Comment: There are tools for that. Why would you want to do that in a text editor? Use a spreadsheet.

Comment: Proof of concept : I simply wondered if it was feasible in Vim even if not reasonable.

Comment: awk is born to do this kind of thing. if you **really** want to do it in vim. you could write a function, split the line into list, you could filter different fields with different logic. I won't recommend to use regex to do this kind of filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following generic form will match the numeric parts of your format:

```
^\s*-\?\d\+\s\+-\?\d\+
```

To implement restrictions on the numbers, replace each `-\?\d\+` with a more specific pattern. For example, for `<= -50`:

```
-\([5-9][0-9]\|[1-9][0-9]\{2,}\)
```

That is, `-` followed by either a 2 digit number where the first digit is >= 5, or a >= 3 digit number.

Similarly, for `>= 250`:

```
\(2[5-9][0-9]\|[3-9][0-9]\{2,}\)
```

Combining the two:

```
^\s*-\([5-9][0-9]\|[1-9][0-9]\{2,}\)\s\+\(2[5-9][0-9]\|[3-9][0-9]\{2,}\)
```

If you also need to filter by some pattern in the description, append that:

```
^\s*-\([5-9][0-9]\|[1-9][0-9]\{2,}\)\s\+\(2[5-9][0-9]\|[3-9][0-9]\{2,}\)\s\+.\{-}Greece
```

`.\{-}` is the lazy version of `.*`.

To filter by this pattern and write the output to a file, use the following:

```
:g/pattern/.w filename
```

Thus, to filter by "first number <= -50 AND second number >= 250 AND 'Greece' in description" and write the output to `greece.out`:

```
:g/^\s*-\([5-9][0-9]\|[1-9][0-9]\{2,}\)\s\+\(2[5-9][0-9]\|[3-9][0-9]\{2,}\)\s\+.\{-}Greece/.w greece.out
```

More complex ranges quickly make this even more ridiculous; you're probably better off parsing the file and filtering with something other than regex.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer which seems to confirm what romainl said : for that sort of question, Vim can only lead to a "feasible" contraption (I do not target your answer which was very clear about the process being ridiculous). Thanks again.